# Kurento websocket connection close after a couple of minutes

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, kurento

I am configuring SSL on kurento using nginx on frontend. But my webSocket connection break after 4 minutes. Here is my nginix conf inside sites-enabled.

```
server {

    listen 443;

    #host name to respond to
    server_name ****.com;
    # your SSL configuration
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/****.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/****.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {

        # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        keepalive_timeout  0;
        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this? I'm running into the same issue